# using meek bridge programmatic

Tags: tor, bridge, stem

I am working on a tor launcher using stem.process module. my problem is that when i specify tor to use meek bridge, it stop at bootstrapping part. my config:

```
config = { 'SocksPort': '7000', 'ControlPort': '9051', 'UseBridges': '1', 'Bridge': 'meek 0.0.2.0:3 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE url=https://meek.azureedge.net/ front=ajax.aspnetcdn.com' }
```

I am using the default meek bridge provided in this path:

```
TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default\preferences\extension-overrides.js
```

when I set this bridge using tor-browser, it works for me but when i use it programmatic, it will freeze. thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:**
I found the answer, my mistake was to not considering pluggable transpoorts at all.

when you want to specify bridges in tor config, you must specify a proper pluggable transport to be used for. in my case i specify a *meek_lite* pluggable transport to be used for my *meek_lite* type bridge's.

The proper solution for my problem:

```
config = {

 'SocksPort': '7000', 'ControlPort': '9051', 'UseBridges': '1', 

'ClientTransportPlugin': 'meek_lite exec {}'.format(obfs4_binary_path),

'Bridge': 'meek 0.0.2.0:3 97700DFE9F483596DDA6264C4D7DF7641E1E39CE 
url=https://meek.azureedge.net/ front=ajax.aspnetcdn.com' 

}
```